# Rails - Validations make my database populating script to stop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I am using the Twitter gem to populate my database with some data about tweets. I set up the following validation `validates :link, uniqueness: true` and it causes my script to stop when it meets tweets already present in my model.

Here is my model :

```
class Twit < ApplicationRecord
 validates :link, uniqueness: true

 def self.get_tweets user
  all_tweets = CLIENT.user_timeline(user, count: "30", exclude_replies: true, include_rts: false)
  all_tweets.each do |tweet|
   Twit.create!(content: "#{tweet.text}", link: "#{tweet.uri}", like: "#{tweet.favorite_count}", retweet: "#{tweet.retweet_count}", first_date: "#{tweet.created_at}")
  end
 end

end
```

I'd like my script to keep creating only new tweets in my model.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use `find_or_create_by` instead of create like
Twit.find_or_create_by(content: "#{tweet.text}") do |twit|
  twit.link = 'xxxxx'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
def self.get_tweets user
  all_tweets = CLIENT.user_timeline(user, count: "30", exclude_replies: true, include_rts: false)
  all_tweets.each do |tweet|
    Twit.where(
       content: "#{tweet.text}", 
       link: "#{tweet.uri}", 
       like: "#{tweet.favorite_count}", 
       retweet: "#{tweet.retweet_count}", 
       first_date: "#{tweet.created_at}"
     ).first_or_create!
  end
end
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: what will happen when like and re tweet will increase?

Comment: This will create those entries

Answer (score 0):

If you just dont want it to save the tweets that is already in the database you can just remove the `!`, then it won't raise and error, but it won't store changes to the like value and the retweet value.

```
   Twit.create(content: "#{tweet.text}", link: "#{tweet.uri}", like: "#{tweet.favorite_count}", retweet: "#{tweet.retweet_count}", first_date: "#{tweet.created_at}")
```

Another way is to use `find_or_create_by` to test if the link is already in the database.

This way you will edit the record that is already in the database, and the tweet will be updated with the new like amount and retweet amount.

```
all_tweets.each do |tweet|
    twit = Twit.find_or_create_by(link: tweet.uri)
    twit.content = tweet.text
    twit.like = tweet.favorite_count
    twit.retweet = tweet.retweet_count
    twit.first_date = tweet.created_at
    twit.save
end
```

Comment: Appreciate your help @lassvi !